# 2D stabilisation with images of different size

Tags: transforms, tracking, 2d

A quick and easy one.

I've several pictures of my face that I would like to transform into a TimeLaps video.

I'm importing them into Movie Clip, then using a 2D stabilization to correct the rotation and scale based on the eyes position.

This works fine.

Except for the pictures that have different sizes (like 3544x1845 , 1475x2544, etc). The scale and position correction is off.

Any idea to solve this ?

Thank for the support.